# Toggle menu if click outside then hide

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a menu where clicking on the account will show the menu and clicking again will close the menu. Again, if someone clicks outside the menu, the menu will close. I can do everything, but if there is a problem, even if I click on a link in the menu, the menu is closed. I want to only close the menu if someone clicks on the account button again and outside the menu. what is the solution?

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
                toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn span')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 200px;
  top: 72px;
  left: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px #0000001a;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 17px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd54;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-side-menu">
  <div class="menu-item" onclick="searchFunction()"><span class="icon fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></span></div>
  <div class="dropbtn menu-item" onclick="myFunction()"><span class="icon fa-regular fa-user"><span class="font">Account</span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><span class="icon fa-regular fa-arrow-right-to-bracket">LogIn</span></a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><span class="icon fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"><span class="font">Write</span></span></a></div>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#"><i class="rbi rbi-bookmark"></i>Saved Article</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-clipboard"></i>My Article</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-chart-bar"></i>My Profile</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="red fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>Log Out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do, is to use [Node.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) to check whether the clicked target is inside your dropdown container or not.

You also have to check whether the target is the button or not. Otherwise, the event listener on the document will immediately close the dropdown once the click event bubbles up from the button to the document (as the button is not inside the dropdown).

And if you already check for the button in the document listener, you don't need a separate button listener.

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector("#myDropdown");
const dropdownBtn = document.querySelector(".dropbtn");

document.addEventListener("click", e => {

  if (dropdownBtn.contains(e.target)) {
    // Button (or span in it) clicked: toggle
    dropdown.classList.toggle("show");
  } else if (!dropdown.contains(e.target)) {
    // Clicked out: hide
    dropdown.classList.remove("show");
  }
  
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 200px;
  top: 72px;
  left: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px #0000001a;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 17px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd54;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-side-menu">
  <div class="menu-item" onclick="searchFunction()"><span class="icon fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></span></div>
  <div class="dropbtn menu-item"><span class="icon fa-regular fa-user"><span class="font">Account</span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><span class="icon fa-regular fa-arrow-right-to-bracket">LogIn</span></a></div>
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="#"><span class="icon fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"><span class="font">Write</span></span></a></div>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#"><i class="rbi rbi-bookmark"></i>Saved Article</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-clipboard"></i>My Article</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-chart-bar"></i>My Profile</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="red fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>Log Out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Different approach

For a better and generalised way to create dropdowns, check out [Kyle's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-VeYcOCFZw).

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to check if someone clicked outside of an element using [Node.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) API. So, the logic is,

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelector("#myDropdown");
addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (!(e.target === dropdown ||  dropdown.contains(e.target))) { // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    dropdown.classList.remove("show"); // hide the dropdown
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. When clicking it removes the show class immediately. Also, there is absolutely no reason to check wheter the element is clicked directly, as .contains returns true anyway. document.contains(document) returns true for example.